# Avoid new user notification on user_save

Tags: users

I'm currently importing a whole bunch of users to a site programmically through user_save. How can I make sure that no registration mails are sent to the users?

```
// Create new user
$newUser = array(
    'name' => $member->name,
    'pass' => $member->password,
    'mail' => $email,
    'field_user_fullname' => array('und' => array(array('value' => $member->navn))),
    'status' => 1,
    );
user_save(null, $newUser);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find a way to do that. user_save doesn't take such an argument. I believe you have two options.

1. Emulate the [user_register_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_register_submit/7) call by passing your data in as a form instead, this is preferably done with [drupal_form_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_form_submit/7). It just so happens that the example deals with user-registration.
2. Just kill outgoing e-mails while you import your users.

Comment: +1 `drupal_form_submit()` would probably be the best way to go

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is you can't I'm afraid, it's hard-coded into the [`user_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7) function with this bit of code:

```
// Send emails after we have the new user object.
if ($account->status != $account->original->status) {
  // The user's status is changing; conditionally send notification email.
  $op = $account->status == 1 ? 'status_activated' : 'status_blocked';
  _user_mail_notify($op, $account);
}
```

That checks the original account object (which is loaded up there and then so it can't be altered) against the new account object and if there's a difference in the status it sends an email.

The only way I can think to do it would be to simulate a submission of the [`user_register_form`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_register_form/7) which has a checkbox denoting whether or not to notify the user of changes.